# Very frequent Wifi disconnection while being in China

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I'm having an issue on my Nexus 4 (Stock Android 5.1.1).

It keeps disconnecting from my Wifi. When I go back to connect, it says "No Internet access, automatic connection impossible".

I currently live in China so my guess is that Android checks if internet is available by querying a Google server, which is blocked in China so it then concludes "No Google = No Internet" and disconnects me from my Wifi.

I can't find any way to disable that Auto-Disconnect "Feature".

Comment: Can you check in your WiFi settings about an option "Avoid poor connections"? Make sure its disabled.

Comment: Nope, there is no such settings. ([Advanced wifi settings screenshot on my phone](http://i.imgur.com/jOzhWks.png))

Comment: Why have you got a VPN running? Disable the vpn and try again.

Comment: Disconnections happen when the VPN is not running (because when it is running, google server are reachable). I had the VPN running on the screenshot in order to be able to upload it. The Wifi settings menu does not change if a VPN is running or not. :/

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176993/how-to-force-android-6-to-automatically-connect-to-a-network-without-internet-ac

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100657/how-to-disable-captive-portal-detection-how-to-remove-exclamation-mark-on-wi-fi

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66964/connect-to-wifi-network-even-if-it-doesnt-have-internet-access

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220414/how-can-i-automatically-re-connect-to-a-wifi-network

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186993/captive-portal-parameters

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218510/android-6-0-1-force-wifi-connection-with-no-internet-access

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I found the solution. Enable airplane mode, then enable wifi. It will show the internet connection is down, but wifi will still work. Then you can disable airplane mode and it will stay connected to the wifi (until you leave the coverage area, then you'll probably need to do it again when you return).

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I no longer live in China and I no longer have the issue I described in my post. So unfortunately, I have no way of testing if your solution works ! Let's hope it'll work for other people having the same issue as I did :)

Comment: This just turns off mobile data, which obviously will make the connection fall back to Wifi. Wifi was never actually disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that Android verifies the connection to a google server.

Guess what's blocked here (China). Right. Google.

Apparently Android's new policy is to prevent auto-connecting to trusted networks if it can't see any internet on the network. Which of course there is, may it be slower and limited to the Chinese Firewall.

So far I haven't found a way in Android to disable this check. And I'm forced to use 3rd party apps to solve this issue.

If I ever find a proper fix, I'll definitely post it here.

[image: Failing to auto-connect]

<sub>Screenshot - Failed to auto-connect (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

I travel here frequently, so I need this.

Comment: I'm assuming the Chinese ROMs use a different verification server?

Comment: No doubt, Fastest servers they can check here are probably from Baidu.

Comment: [Tin-foil-hat-mode] Or probably an other government server, that keeps track of your location.

Comment: Or nothing at all (old style Android)

Comment: This is interesting. It should really check several servers in case one is down or blocked.

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Comment: @Huey Technically it's correct, as there is no "internet" in the broadest sense.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Wifi encrytption. WEP dont seems to work , get it changed to WPA/WPA2

Comment: Do you mean WPA rather than WEP?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I edited the response