# How to force android 6 to automatically connect to a network without internet access?

Tags: stock-android, connection-issues, wifi-hotspot

I've set up a hifiberry(raspberry + dac shield) in my car, which has a wireless access point. I'm using my old sony z3 compact as a headunit. Runeaudio allows you to do all this easily. However, the raspberry is just an access point, there is no modem so it has no internet access.

Normally the phone will connect to networks automatically, but inthis case, it says "no internet access, won't automatically connect" in the wifi options. I have to manually connect it every time.

Is there a way to make it connect automatically, even though there is no internet access?

Comment: This seems strange as android is supposed to automatically connect to automatically to saved networks irrespective of internet access,  otherwise try forgetting the network and reconnect ing

Comment: I can add a screenshot later if you don8

Comment: T believe me. It says it is not automatically connecting explicitly because there is no internet access.

Comment: Oh really, let me see if my device behaves in the same way, i will get back to you

Comment: Figured it out! I guess the phone detects it as captive portal

Comment: The interface for runeaudio is a webpage, runeaudio is the OS running on the pi so that would make sense. Where you able to reproduce it? Ill upload scresnie in 30 mins.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/btXYK

Comment: So how could I go about making it connect automatically? There must be a simple way with an automation app, I couldnt find anything on google though.

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/very-frequent-wifi-disconnection-while-being-in-china

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100657/how-to-disable-captive-portal-detection-how-to-remove-exclamation-mark-on-wi-fi

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66964/connect-to-wifi-network-even-if-it-doesnt-have-internet-access

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220414/how-can-i-automatically-re-connect-to-a-wifi-network

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186993/captive-portal-parameters

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218510/android-6-0-1-force-wifi-connection-with-no-internet-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://binfalse.de/2017/02/07/android-no-internet-access-detected-won-t-automatically-reconnect-aka-connected-no-internet/) since Android 5, when  the device connect to. Wi-Fi network it makes  a quick HTTP request to check if it has internet access.

> This check is, for example, done with
>   `clients3.google.com/generate_204` , a “webpage” that always returns
>   an HTTP status code `204 No Content| . Thus, if the device receives a`
>   204` it is connected to the internet, otherwise it assumes that this
>   network does not provide proper internet access or is just a captive
>   portal.

Most probable resolution is to disable captive portal detection, ad there are a variety of ways to achieve this:

1. **Using AdAway to prevent the HTTP leak (blocking the URL)**

   - Configuration of AdAway which blocks Google’s captive portal detection.

`# captive portal`

```
 127.0.0.1   clients3.google.com

 127.0.0.1   clients.l.google.com
```

2. **Disable captive portal detection**

With a rooted phone you can simply disable captive portal detection. Just get a root-shell through adb (or SSH etc) to run the following command:

```
settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0
```

Additionally see this related question: [How to disable captive portal detection? How to remove exclamation mark on Wi-Fi or signal icon in Lollipop?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/100657/209414)

3. **Change the server for captive portal detection using AdAway**

   Another option for changing the captive portal detection server is to change its IP address to one that’s under your control.

You can do that with AdAway, for example. Let’s say your captive portal detection server has the IP address `5.189.140.231` , then you may add the following to your AdAway configuration:

```
5.189.140.231 clients3.google.com
5.189.140.231 clients.l.google.com
```

The webserver at `5.189.140.231` should then of course accept requests for the foreign domains.

For other workarounds see [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=58252752&postcount=38)

Comment: Thats great! Anytime :)